# C# check if property is new class with properties inside

Tags: c#

```
public class MyModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public AddressModel Address { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

Is it possible somehow to check if `AddressModel` is a new class? If is new class I need to do some checks ...

By new class I mean

```
 public class AddressModel {

[Required]
public string Street{ get; set; }


...
}
```

so not just object but also if has properties inside ...

Comment: Could you please be a bit more explanatory about new class?

Comment: Do you mean has it been persisted before? If that's the case pass the id from the persistance store, if its equal to the default value it does not yet exist in the store otherwise it does.

Comment: `typeof(MyModel).GetProperty("Address", /*binding flags instance*/).PropertyType` this will return type of the property and you can check if property value is default or somthing.

Comment: Please don't delete the question when people ask you what you mean and then simply re-ask it. You've already asked this and people asked what you mean, you should've edited your existing question and provided more information. I realize you've provided more information here but get into the habit of editing your existing question instead of delete+reask.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this part: (the rest is not clear to me)

> so not just object but also if has properties inside ...

You could check whether the type has properties using reflection:

```
 Console.WriteLine(typeof(AddressModel).GetProperties().Count());
```

this is also possible using an instance of that class:

```
AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
Console.WriteLine(model.GetType().GetProperties().Count());
```

Comment: In this case, possibly `MyModel myModel = new MyModel(); if(myModel.Address != null) { /* Perform reflection on myModel.Address.GetType() */ }` but this needs clarity from OP as the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ColinM you're right, I restricted the range of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is *very vague* even if while *testing* we should be esp. attentive to *details*. E.g. imagine classes

```
 public abstract class WeirdModel {
   // It's not me who implement this readonly property 
   protected abstract String Something {get;}
 }

 public class EerieModel {
   // write-only banned property  
   [Obsolete("Do not call obsolete properties!", true)]
   public string DoNotCallMe(set {...})
 }

 public class PrivateModel {
   // That's for me only
   private string PersonalInfo {get; set;} 
 } 

 public class StaticModel {
   // One property for all instances
   public static string CommonInfo {get; set;} 
 }
```

Do you consider these class being *new* ones? In any case you have to get properties, filter out them and finally check if *any* such a property exists:

```
 var isNew = typeof(AddressModel)
   .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
   .Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite)
   .Where(property => property.GetAccessors().All(method => !method.IsAbstract))      
    //TODO: put more conditions on properties if you want
   ...
   .Any();
```